# Using Spyder IDE fo Power BI

Tags: powerbi, spyder

I am new to PowerBI and I am trying to use Spyder to write python script for PowerBI instead of VSC. Is possible? There is no .exe in Spyder. BTW, I downloaded Spyder alone without Anaconda.

Comment: I'm also starting with Spyder and I would recommend to install the whole Anaconda environment. Spyder seems to work better this way. I tried to use Spyder with the default Python installation of python.org and I run into difficulties.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.